# How can I make a ball accelerate while moving down?

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I am making a super monkey ball game.

I want my ball to gain velocity while rolling downwards infinitely, and I cannot find any solution to this on Google. I'm new with c# so I am having a hard time creating this code on my own, can anybody help me achieve this?

I figured the question is simple enough not to require a picture or file. In layman's terms, I want the ball to roll faster and faster while as it rolls down a slope.

I am using Unities rigidboody, which adds velocity while to falling speed, but does not add velocity to rolling speed

I decided to test it with a steeper slope and it seems the rotational velocity worked, however I cant have the game have this difficulty, as the slope has to be very steep for the angular velocity to work properly. I have no angular or normal drag, so is there a way to change the slope the ball has to be rolling at for velocity to work? Or is unities rigidbody just not very good for a game like this.

Comment: Just to be clear, which velocity do you want to accelerate, downward velocity (velocity in the negative y direction) or angular velocity (how fast it rotates, regardless of where it is in the world)?

Comment: This should come out of the box. If you're finding rolling speed is hitting a plateau, it could be that you have too much friction/drag/dampening, or you have a script modifying the ball's lateral velocity that's preventing it from accumulating correctly. Do you have any scripts in play at the moment?